# Background color or image doesn't show. HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, background

So, i have an index.html file that has a header div, then under the header div there is a container div that has another child div called images. I am trying to put a background color or image with css but something seems to go wrong. I can't find out what it is.

***Here is the HTML***

```
<div class="container"> <!-- Start of the Container -->
<div class="images">
<img src="images/quotes/photo1.jpg" id="first_image">
<img src="images/quotes/photo2.jpg">
<img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
<img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" id="first_image">
<img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
<img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
<img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" id="first_image">
<img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
<img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
</div> 
</div> <!-- End of the Container -->
```

***Here is the CSS***

```
 .container{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background:url("images/background.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-size:contain;
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to put a background on the container div. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the id, i was testing something... Although i cant find the answer to my question... I am trying for almost 2 hours...

Comment: You are probably overwriting the background somewhere else.  Try using Firebug to inspect the elements and it will show you the CSS being applied all the way up and down the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your ID's should be unique. So change your HTML to :

```
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Start of the Container -->
        <div class="images">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo1.jpg" id="first_image">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo2.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" id="second_image">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" id="third_image">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
        </div>
</div>
```

Secondly, If you want to 'group' them use class instead as below :

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- Start of the Container -->
        <div class="images">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo1.jpg" class="imgGrp" id="first_image">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo2.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" class="imgGrp" id="second_image">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" class="imgGrp" id="third_image">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
            <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
        </div>
</div>
```

Thirdly, use relative addressing for referencing your image in `background` in `CSS`. If you use it correctly, this should work as below

```
.container {
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZHzX.jpg");
     background-size:cover;
     background-size:contain;
  }
```

***NOTE*** : Also, note that you can combine the CSS background properties into a single statement by making use of the `background` shorthand property. The background shorthand property is made up of eight other properties:

```
background-image
background-position
background-size
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-origin
background-clip
background-color
```

Hence, the shorthand property can be written as :

```
background : <background-image> <background-position> <background-size> <background-repeat> <background-attachment> <background-origin> <background-clip> <background-color>
```

You can effectively modify the below CSS class (*the image url*) as per your needs. However, this is just to demonstrate a general idea :

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background: url('http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png') top center no-repeat orange;
  height : 400px;
}
```

Please see this in action in the snippet below :

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background: url('http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png') top center no-repeat orange;
  height : 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <!-- Start of the Container -->
            <div class="images">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo1.jpg" class="imgGrp" id="first_image">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo2.jpg">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" class="imgGrp" id="second_image">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo4.jpg" class="imgGrp" id="third_image">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo5.jpg">
                <img src="images/quotes/photo3.jpg">
            </div>
    </div>
```